# Nodejs writestream memory usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

Look at this sample code, that makes a copy of a file in nodejs.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var out = fs.createWriteStream('1_GB_FILE_COPY');
var inp = fs.createReadStream('1_GB_FILE');
inp.pipe(out);
inp.on('end', function() {
  console.log("end");
})
process.stdin.on('data', function() {});//just to keep process alive after copy
```

All good, this code works and the copy is made. Nodejs uses around 140MB of memory during the copy. But after the copy is made, it never deallocates this memory. Is this normal? why node keep this memory? is there any way to force it to flush it?

Comment: How do you know the memory is not deallocated?

Comment: from system monitor! it uses 140mb of ram even after copy has completed.

Answer (score 0):

The system monitor gives you a very inaccurate view into what kind of memory usage your node application is actually using. There's a big difference between how your operating system allocates memory to processes and how node manages its own memory. You can use the chrome dev tools to get a better look. I ran your code taking before and after memory snapshot, compared the two and found the following:

[image]

In short, you're definitely not leaking 140MB like you might think. To see this for yourself, here's a nice guide to follow:

https://github.com/felixge/node-memory-leak-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Let's say that in an extreme situation we only had 140MB of free memory and nodejs getting it, completing the job, and as you say it frees it, does the OS thinks that this is memory is free again or that it doesnt have any free memory at all?